# loop invariant proof

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof, loop-invariants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof of linear search?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6597/proof-of-linear-search)

I'm reading the MIT Press, Introduction to Algorithms textbook 3rd edition, and I am a bit confused by an exercise.

2.1-3
Consider the searching problem:
Input: A sequence of n numbers A =  and a value v.
Output: An index i such that v = A[i] or the special value NIL if v does not appear in A.

Write pseudocode for linear search, which scans through the sequence looking for v. Using a loop invariant, prove that your algorithm is correct. Make sure your loop invariant fulfills the three necessary properties.

Earlier in the book I read that "We must show three things about a loop invariant:

Initialization: It is true prior to the first iteration of the loop.

Maintenance: If it is true before an iteration of the loop, it remains true before the
next iteration.

Termination: When the loop terminates, the invariant gives us a useful property that helps show that the algorithm is correct.
"

I wrote this as my pseudocode

```
index = nil
j = 1 
while j <= A.length and index == nil
  if A[j] == v
    index = j
  j = j + 1
```

But when it comes to proving using a loop invariant I have no idea what to do. What do I even use as a loop invariant? To be honest I'm not really clear about the entire loop invariant concept. Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, I suggest you search for other questions. There are many concerning loop invariants.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35112/tips-for-constructing-basic-loop-invariants. Very briefly, you use loop invariants to prove something about a program with a loop; it's an essential part of a proof by induction.

Comment: @ShyPerson Hm, I think loop invariants are more tied to formal semantics (cf Hoare logic/rules) than induction proofs; it is clear how a loop invariant resembles the induction hypothesis and proof obligation in the inductive step, though.